# findFragmentByTag returning null in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to call a fragment method from its parent activity. For that i want object of fragment.

parent activity have fragment in framelayout like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_buttons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

This is the code for getting fragment object.

```
FragmentBottomButtons fragment = new FragmentBottomButtons();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.bottom_buttons, fragment,"FragmentTag");
        //ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        //ft.addToBackStack("");
        ft.commit();


        /*
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.bottom_buttons, new FragmentBottomButtons())
                .commit();

        */
        frag = (FragmentBottomButtons) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentTag");
        //fragmentBottomButtons = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottom_buttons);
        if (frag == null){
            Utility.displayToast("fragmnt is null");
        }
```

But it is returning null.

can anyone help me on this? what is wrong here?

Comment: Try executing fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions(); before getting the fragment see if that works. commit() works asynchronously and its possible to call it before the action is fully completed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you using `commit()` method nobody gives to you guarantee that your fragment will be attached to FragmentManager on the fly.

This happens due to inner `FragmentManager` logic : when you add\replace\remove any fragments you create a `FragmentTransaction` and puts it into execution queue inside FragmentManager. Actually all Transactions waiting until FragmentManager enqueue tasks.

To avoid this situation you can force enqueue each task under Fragment via

```
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTranscation();
```

This method starts pending Transactions and make more hard sure for use `findFragmentById()` method.

So, finally you need :

```
CustomFragment fragment = new CustomFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//add or replace or remove fragment
ft.commit();

getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTranscation();

CustomFragment customFragment = (CustomFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentTag");
```

Comment: You will get  "FragmentManager is already executing transactions"

Answer (score 0):

Your `Fragment` is not attached yet. You need to call `findFragmentByTag()` later on. You can for exemple add a listener to you `Fragment` and call your `Activity` on the `onAttach()` method to tell your `Activity` that your `Fragment` is created.